# Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::has()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

When i access my Laravel Project. It Returns Following Errors. How to Solve It.

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::has(), called in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ViewErrorBag.php on line 92 and defined (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

**In my Blade Code :**

```
  @if ($errors->has())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}<br>
  @endforeach
  </div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this line:

```
@if ($errors->has())
```

`has()` is used to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So it acts very similarly to a normal `WHERE` condition. If you just use `has('relation')` that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

`has()` must have a string index as its parameter to check whether it exist or not. But in your case it is blank.

Replace the following line:

```
@if ($errors->has())
```

with

```
@if ($errors->count())
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks @MayankPandeyz

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
@if ($errors->has())
```

Use in Laravel 5.3

```
@if ($errors->count())
```

Comment: + for using laravel function instead of pure php. This should be the correct answer.