# Error on MessageBag::has()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have simple message alerts on the page for various actions. It's look like this

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
    <hr />
@endif
```

From another thread here on SO which was resolved I've tried to count them

```
@if(count(Session::has('message')) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
    <hr />
@endif
```

but still I get this error

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::has(), called in /var/www/html/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ViewErrorBag.php on line 92

What is this means and what is this argument which is missing?

Update: As I said I have tried this and you can see it in my question. `@if(count(Session::has('message')) > 0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::has()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445304/missing-argument-1-for-illuminate-support-messagebaghas)

Comment: I've updated my question. It's same problem but the solution doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that `Session::has('message')` will return a boolean and you can't count a boolean !

Comment: @Maraboc I've tried with isset too `@if(isset(Session::has('message')))` still same

Comment: It's the same, instead pass a collection of errors to your view and you can count the errors like this `count( $errors )`

Comment: How to pass the $errors when I pass the message from controller `return Redirect::to('/contact')->with('message', 'Message sent. We will get in touch as soon as possible');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case you can do like this :

```
@if(isset($message)))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ $message }}</div>
    <hr />
@endif
```

Comment: Why this error doesn't happen on laravel 4.2 but it has in 5.4